# The menu does not work when you log in it appears blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

can you help me? I am developing an app with the stack mean I have a problem when I start the session in the app. The menu options seem to be blocked and I must refresh the page so that they are enabled.

Any ideas?

I am using the version of Materialize 1.0.0 and jquery 3.4.1

The template is the following but I update it to the new versions of materialize and jquery I do not know if I need to modify something else:

[https://github.com/rahmato/free-materialize-material-design-admin-template][1]

This is the menu code:

```html
    <header id="header" class="page-topbar" *ngIf="auth.isLoggedIn()">
          <!-- start header nav-->
          <div class="navbar-fixed">
            <nav class="navbar-color gradient-45deg-light-blue-cyan">
              <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <ul class="left">
                  <li>
                    <h1 class="logo-wrapper">
                      <a href="index.html" class="brand-logo darken-1">
                        <img src="../../../assets/images/logo/materialize-logo.png" alt="materialize logo">
                        <span class="logo-text hide-on-med-and-down">Materialize</span>
                      </a>
                    </h1>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                  <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="waves-effect waves-block waves-light translation-button" data-target="translation-dropdown">
                      <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="waves-effect waves-block waves-light toggle-fullscreen">
                      <i class="material-icons">settings_overscan</i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="waves-effect  notification-button" data-target="notifications-dropdown">
                      <i class="material-icons">notifications_none
                        <small class="notification-badge pink accent-2">5</small>
                      </i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-block waves-light profile-button" data-target="profile-dropdown">
                      <span class="avatar-status avatar-online">
                        <img src="../../../assets/images/avatar/avatar-7.png" alt="avatar">
                        <i></i>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" data-target="chat-out" class="waves-effect waves-block waves-light chat-collapse">
                      <i class="material-icons">format_indent_increase</i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- translation-button -->
                <ul id="translation-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#!" class="grey-text text-darken-1">
                      <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb"></i> English</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#!" class="grey-text text-darken-1">
                      <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"></i> French</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#!" class="grey-text text-darken-1">
                      <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-cn"></i> Chinese</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#!" class="grey-text text-darken-1">
                      <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-de"></i> German</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- notifications-dropdown -->
                <ul id="notifications-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                  <li>
                    <h6>NOTIFICATIONS
                      <span class="new badge">5</span>
                    </h6>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#!" class="grey-text text-darken-2">
                      <span class="material-icons icon-bg-circle cyan small">add_shopping_cart</span> A new order has been placed!</a>
                    <time class="media-meta" datetime="2015-06-12T20:50:48+08:00">2 hours ago</time>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#!" class="grey-text text-darken-2">
                      <span class="material-icons icon-bg-circle red small">stars</span> Completed the task</a>
                    <time class="media-meta" datetime="2015-06-12T20:50:48+08:00">3 days ago</time>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#!" class="grey-text text-darken-2">
                      <span class="material-icons icon-bg-circle teal small">settings</span> Settings updated</a>
                    <time class="media-meta" datetime="2015-06-12T20:50:48+08:00">4 days ago</time>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#!" class="grey-text text-darken-2">
                      <span class="material-icons icon-bg-circle deep-orange small">today</span> Director meeting started</a>
                    <time class="media-meta" datetime="2015-06-12T20:50:48+08:00">6 days ago</time>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#!" class="grey-text text-darken-2">
                      <span class="material-icons icon-bg-circle amber small">trending_up</span> Generate monthly report</a>
                    <time class="media-meta" datetime="2015-06-12T20:50:48+08:00">1 week ago</time>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- profile-dropdown -->
                <ul id="profile-dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="grey-text text-darken-1">
                      <i class="material-icons">face</i> Profile</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="grey-text text-darken-1">
                      <i class="material-icons">settings</i> Settings</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="grey-text text-darken-1">
                      <i class="material-icons">live_help</i> Help</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="grey-text text-darken-1">
                      <i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i> Lock</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="grey-text text-darken-1" (click)="auth.logout()">
                      <i class="material-icons">keyboard_tab</i> Logout</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
          <!-- end header nav-->
        </header>
```

and This is the script:

```js
    /*Preloader*/
    $(window).on('load', function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('body').addClass('loaded');
      }, 200);
    });

    $(function () {

      "use strict";

      var window_width = $(window).width();


      // Search class for focus
      $('.header-search-input').focus(
        function () {
          $(this).parent('div').addClass('header-search-wrapper-focus');
        }).blur(
          function () {
            $(this).parent('div').removeClass('header-search-wrapper-focus');
          });

      // Check first if any of the task is checked
      $('#task-card input:checkbox').each(function () {
        checkbox_check(this);
      });

      // Task check box
      $('#task-card input:checkbox').change(function () {
        checkbox_check(this);
      });

      // Check Uncheck function
      function checkbox_check(el) {
        if (!$(el).is(':checked')) {
          $(el).next().css('text-decoration', 'none'); // or addClass
        } else {
          $(el).next().css('text-decoration', 'line-through'); //or addClass
        }
      }
      // Plugin initialization

      $('select').formSelect();
      // Set checkbox on forms.html to indeterminate
      var indeterminateCheckbox = document.getElementById('indeterminate-checkbox');
      if (indeterminateCheckbox !== null)
        indeterminateCheckbox.indeterminate = true;

      $('.profile-btn').dropdown({
        inDuration: 300,
        outDuration: 225,
        constrainWidth: false,
        gutter: 0,
        coverTrigger: false,
        alignment: 'right',
        stopPropagation: false
      });

      // Commom, Translation & Horizontal Dropdow

      $('.dropdown-trigger, .translation-button, .dropdown-menu').dropdown({
        inDuration: 300,
        outDuration: 225,
        constrainWidth: false,
        hover: true,
        gutter: 0,
        coverTrigger: false,
        alignment: 'left',
        stopPropagation: false
      });
      // Notification, Profile & Settings Dropdown
      $('.notification-button, .profile-button, .dropdown-settings').dropdown({
        inDuration: 300,
        outDuration: 225,
        constrainWidth: false,
        hover: true,
        gutter: 0,
        coverTrigger: false,
        alignment: 'right',
        stopPropagation: false
      });

      // Materialize scrollSpy
      $('.scrollspy').scrollSpy();

      // Materialize tooltip
      $('.tooltipped').tooltip({
        delay: 50
      });

      //Main Left Sidebar Menu
      $('.sidenav').sidenav({
        edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
        preventScrolling: false
      });

      // Overlay Menu (Full screen menu)
      $('.menu-sidebar-collapse').sidenav({
        menuWidth: 240,
        edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
        //sidenav-close:true, // Set if default menu open is true
        //menuOut: false // Set if default menu open is true
      });

      //Main Left Sidebar Chat
      $('.chat-collapse').sidenav({
        menuWidth: 300,
        edge: 'right',
      });

      // Pikadate datepicker
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
      });

      // Perfect Scrollbar
      $('select').not('.disabled').formSelect();
      var leftnav = $(".page-topbar").height();
      var leftnavHeight = window.innerHeight - leftnav;
      if (!$('#slide-out.leftside-navigation').hasClass('native-scroll')) {
        $('.leftside-navigation').perfectScrollbar({
          suppressScrollX: true
        });
      }
      var righttnav = $("#chat-out").height();
      $('.rightside-navigation').perfectScrollbar({
        suppressScrollX: true
      });

      // Fullscreen
      function toggleFullScreen() {
        if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
          (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
          if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
          } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
          } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
          }
        } else {
          if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
          } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
          } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
          }
        }
      }

      $('.toggle-fullscreen').click(function () {
        toggleFullScreen();
      });

      // Toggle Flow Text
      var toggleFlowTextButton = $('#flow-toggle')
      toggleFlowTextButton.click(function () {
        $('#flow-text-demo').children('p').each(function () {
          $(this).toggleClass('flow-text');
        })
      });

      // Detect touch screen and enable scrollbar if necessary
      function is_touch_device() {
        try {
          document.createEvent("TouchEvent");
          return true;
        } catch (e) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      if (is_touch_device()) {
        $('#nav-mobile').css({
          overflow: 'auto'
        })
      }
    });
```

Comment: Why you put angular, while there is no angular at all.

Comment: Please provide https://stackblitz.com link to the source code. This helps tracing the issue.